# advantage Parquev vs Avro

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, avro

Parquet is a column based format. So the fast reading of selected columns is declared as a main advantage of Parquet by comparison with other formats.

I decided to compare the speed of reading of parquet and avro files, by Spark (Java 8) at local.

For example, the model:

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private int number;
    public String client;
    private String claim;
    // getters/setters
{
```

I generate identical parquet and avro file with 1000000 records: Number is the increasing sequence of unical integers, Client is a set of 20 random repeated values, Claim is a set of unical values.

The reading of parquet:

```
 public void readParquet(){
    Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = spark.read().parquet("orders_parquet");
    parquetFileDF.createOrReplaceTempView("orders");
    long beginTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    spark.sql("SELECT id FROM orders");
    long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("parquet select " + (endTime2 - beginTime2));
 }
```

And reading of avro:

```
 public void readAvro(){     
    Dataset<Row> parquetFileDF = spark.read().format("avro").load("orders_avro");
    long beginTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    parquetFileDF.select("client");
    long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("avro select " + (endTime2 - beginTime2));
 }
```

As a result of first attempt, the Spark spent for reading selected "client" item in parquet file **50109200** nonoseconds (50 mlns), and in avro file... **12253000** nanoseconds (12 mlns). Next attempts show the same result.

So, avro files are readen 4 times faster than parquet files. It don't corresponds to declared advantage of parquet format in reading operations.

Or, may be I missing out some important details?

Answer (score 1):

> "So the fast reading of selected columns is declared as a main
> advantage of Parquet by comparison with other formats."

i think selected is a key here. If i understand it correctly you are reading whole dataset so you need to read whole row anyway, thats why column based format is not going to help You imo.

For example Parquet shines when you have wide records, lets say with 100 columns, and you need to read only two values. For example during aggregations you dont need to read whole row - which is a case in row based format

You are running it on local machine so probably you are going to read from one disc anyway. In other cases it may also make difference, as in case of full scan of row based table you may need to get the data from many discs (because you need to read everything) but in columnar format not

Other thing is that in case of parquet you are creating temp view, for avro not

You may find more details in this [article](https://dataschool.com/data-modeling-101/row-vs-column-oriented-databases/)

Comment: M_S, I was looking towards temp view too.  In a case of Spark we read selected data not directly from file, but from temp view.   I also compared "direct" reading from parquet and avro (the whole file). For parquet it took 235 millions of ns, and for avro - 23 millions of ns.  But it's not a selected reading.  May, be the Spark is not a best tool for this benchmarking, and it's better to use other instrument?

Comment: I am not sure if Spark is a problem here and with other tool it will be more precise, maybe spark overhead is a key here - i dont know. Perhaps you should take a look at files. Are they both compresed? Maybe only parquet is compressed and thats the reason? I think that you can also try to generate files with more columns and records to do other tests, maybe with bigger volume results are going to be different